# Ascensor plugin - trigger function "WindowsOn" change

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Good day - this is my first ever post on StackOverflow and i'm a bit of a noob when it come to jQuery & JS... So go easy on me :) here it goes...

I am recreating my portfolio site and am using several jQuery plugins. One of which is the jquery.ascensor.js plugin, found here - [Ascensor Plugin](http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/#/Home)

It all works perfectly, except i'm trying to add a (Hope this is the right terminology) a custom callback function, that will allow me to animate (Using css3) when a specific "ascensorFloor1,2,3...etc" comes into view and then disappears when out of view... I hope this make sense.

This is my HTML calling the plugin:

```
$('#ascensorBuilding').ascensor({
        AscensorName:'ascensor',
        ChildType:'section',
        AscensorFloorName:'Home | Implementation | HTML | Jquery | CSS | Smartphone | Credits',
        Time:1000,
        WindowsOn:1,
        Direction:'chocolate',
        AscensorMap:'2|1 & 2|2 & 2|3 & 2|4 & 2|5 & 1|5 & 2|6',
        Easing:'easeInOutQuad',
        KeyNavigation:true,
        Queued:false
    });
```

HTML in the body:

```
<section id="ascensorFloor1" class="ascensorFloor" style="position: absolute; width: 1920px; height: 955px; left: 3840px; top: 955px;">
    <article class="container_12">
        <h1>Content for Floor 1</h1>
    </article>
</section>
<section id="ascensorFloor2" class="ascensorFloor" style="position: absolute; width: 1920px; height: 955px; left: 3840px; top: 955px;">
    <article class="container_12">
        <h1>Content for Floor 2</h1>
    </article>
</section>
<section id="ascensorFloor3" class="ascensorFloor" style="position: absolute; width: 1920px; height: 955px; left: 3840px; top: 955px;">
    <article class="container_12">
            <h1>Content for Floor 3</h1>
    </article>
</section>
```

I think i will be able to handle the CSS3 code, just need a little help on the jQuery 'Callback' function.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Probably not the most elegant way to do this, but I attached the functions to the hash change event using Ben Alman's hashChange plugin. here is the code I added:                                                                           `$(window).hashchange( function() {
      var value = window.location.hash.substr(2);  
   if (value === 'HASH_VALUE'){
        $('#test').show();
   } else {
  $('#test').hide();
   }
      return false; 
});`                                                                              would be great to get some feedback from anyone. A better method?

Comment: How do you configure ascensor js to make it change window.location.hash value?? In a fresh install, ascensor doesn't do it. Then hashChange can't detect when a slide has changed. Thanks

Comment: I know this is late, but it seams that the newer version has removed the hashChange functionality. I don't know why, it was a deal breaker for me.